# Do not show files under a directory tree with a certain extension

Tags: git, unix, csh

I want not to show files under A/B/C/*.bak (A/B/C - tree directoies)

I wrote this command in unix (it's under repository):

```
git ls-files | grep -Ev '(^A/B/C*\.bak)'
```

But it doesn't work because it doen't understand the meaning of '*'

What's the correct way to do it ?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use `exclude` [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec):

```
git ls-files . ':!A/B/C/**.bak'
```

(`**` means "in any subdirectory").

Second, `grep` doesn't operate on filename wildcards (`*.bak`), it matches regular expressions. You know that because you escaped the dot (`*\.bak`). Well, you need to understand that wildcard `*` also must be converted to RE; it's `.*`. So try

```
git ls-files | grep -Ev '(^A/B/C/.*\.bak)'
```

Comment: I used '\' before dot because unix will ignore dot without it. But maybe I'm confused with another topic.
Can you point me to a good guide/tutorial for it ? @phd

Comment: @Alex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression , [`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep), https://regex101.com/